# Find the parent Element in an invalid XML string at a given position

Tags: xml, regex

Example:

```
...some string content here...
<test>
    <a>
        ...something...
    </a>
    <a/>
    {position 1}
    <b>{position 2}
        <c>
            ...something else...
            {position 3}
        </c>
        <c/>
        <d>
            <e/>
            {position 4}
            <e>
                ...another thing here...
                {position 5}
            </e>
        </d>
        {position 6}
    </b>
    {position 7}
...more xml and other sting content...
```

> I need to find the parent enclosing element at (e.g.) the positions
>   specified above.
>
> The results would be: {position 1} = test {position 2} = b {position
>   3} = c {position 4} = d {position 5} = e {position 6} = b {position 7}
>   = test
>
> Remarks:
>   - None of any element tag names are known
>   - The hole string may include non xml content
>   - The size of the data is very big (>50MB text file)

There must be a search technique implemented to read backward starting at the given position until a valid match (if any) is found.

Thanx

Comment: What language are you using?  Do you have the option of loading this string into an XML object and then doing a find parent function?  That seems like it would be the smoother solution than a regex.

Comment: Every language I know has great xml parsers or wraps libxml or the like.  If the data is huge, use a streaming parser like expat.

Comment: Language: C#
Its too large to be loaded and also, it contains invalid content or unacceptable characters

Comment: Also, some elements may not have matching ending...

Comment: Why do you want to parse an invalid XML file baffles me

Comment: Yes, it is not xml, but the data that are important are placed inside some xml elements.
The element names are needed to build the complete valid xml, containing that data.

Comment: I also found that intellisense-like method could be used.

Comment: @m0skit0
The content is big and some places include xml that may be scrambled.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid XML can't be parsed, by definition.  That is why any XML parser out there will simply refuse to parse it and return an error.

If XML parsers can't parse it, neither can you (basically).  What you are asking for is not some simple string or simple collection of tags that can be grabbed by a regex.  You really have to do a *complete parse* (of possibly invalid data!) in order to find the parent tags at a particular location.

**Update:** to see what I am talking about, think about finding the parent of `{position 1}` in your example.

- A simplistic starting approach to this problem might be "go backwards and find the opening tag".  But you clearly can't take the first opening tag you find (`<a>`), because that closes before the position.
- So, as you go backwards, you have to see `</a>` and remember that the `<a>` tag was closed, so that you don't count `<a>` as the parent.
- And of course, there could be an arbitrary amount of opened and closed tags before you get to the parent.  You have to keep track of all of them (including multiple occurrences of the same tag).

As you can see, this is quite complicated.  And that is before you allow for any *invalid elements* in the file.

One simple approach that might work: if you know exactly what the files error's are, you could remove those errors, then feed the corrected file into an XML parser.

Otherwise, you would have to write your own custom parser for your particular brand of invalid XML.  And it may not even be possible, depending on the type of errors are in the file.

Comment: That was the first thought. Remove errors and parse, but, some tags have no coresponding closing tag and this will result in loss of some data. Also, there are custom tags e.g. <info:title id="">... where I dont know the namespace names. Although I can use xmlreader settings to ignore namespaces I will have to load the entire xml.
I currently read only backwards from the given position and try to reach the starting element name where I call it "root node" of the position.

Comment: @mtsiakiris, if "some tags have no corresponding closing tag" I think your task is basically impossible.

Comment: impossible?  no, nothing is impossible.. it just matters on how complicated you need to make it.  maybe improbable would be more accurate.
@mtsiakiris, I think that you are stuck doing what you have been doing.  Starting from your known point and reading backwards until you have reached your "parent node".  This will not be pretty.

Comment: @cepatt, a file with unmatched tags can contain ambiguities such that there will be no correct answer to the question "what is the parent node?"  In that case, the task is clearly impossible.

Comment: @cepatt, I only want the tag name of the call it "root" element of the current position. I dont care if it is enclosed inside a well-formed xml. May be the only way is to search backwards while keeping all valid parent element tag names until a non closing parent element is found. As dan1111 said.